How to create REST API endpoints for core_config_data table?
I am working on an integration extension for Magento 2. I would like to create API endpoints for core_config_data table, because I would like to insert a html script to header of each specific store view.
Let's say that the Magento store has these records in core_config_data_table:
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                  | value                |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|        47 | stores  |        1 | design/head/includes  | <link  SOMETHING />  |
|        48 | stores  |        3 | design/head/includes  | <link  SOMETHING />  |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+----------------------+

I would like to end up with something like this:
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                  | value                                                    |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|        47 | stores  |        1 | design/head/includes  | <link  SOMETHING /><script async="" src=URL-1></script>  |
|        48 | stores  |        3 | design/head/includes  | <link  SOMETHING /><script async="" src=URL-2></script>  |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+

I can figure out which value I want to include for which scope_id (store view id), but I don't know how to implement the endpoints that i need for this.
I think I need 2 endpoints:

endpoint to fetch the current value in path design/head/includes for specific scope_id


I need this because I want to extend the value, not replace it


endpoint to update the value in path design/head/includes for specific scope_id

How should I go about solving this?

In custom module you have to do these steps, in here endpoint is
/V1/kzcomfortgrade/getcomfortgrade
You dont need 2 endpoints as one will serve the purpose
1.
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Kz\Comfortgrade\Api;

interface GetcomfortgradeManagementInterface
{

    /**
     * GET for getcomfortgrade api
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGetcomfortgrade();
}


in etc/webapi.xml
<route url="/V1/kzcomfortgrade/getcomfortgrade" method="GET">
    <service class="Kz\Comfortgrade\Api\GetcomfortgradeManagementInterface" method="getGetcomfortgrade"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>




<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Kz\Comfortgrade\Model;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;


class GetcomfortgradeManagement implements \Kz\Comfortgrade\Api\GetcomfortgradeManagementInterface
{

    protected $eavConfig;

        public function __construct(
             ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,

            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter

        ) {
            $this->_configWriter = $configWriter;
            $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;




        }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getGetcomfortgrade()
    {
        $ftp_server = $this->scopeConfig->getValue("ftp_settings/settings/ftp_server",ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $updateValue= $ftp_server. "html";
        $this->_configWriter->save("ftp_settings/settings/ftp_server", $updateValue, "default", 1);
        
    }
}


Thank You! I had to do some editing to fit my use case but this answer was definitely a huge help

Glad it helps, cheers !!
